# Fastest way to migrate Linux data

Tags: linux, software-raid, grub, disk-image

I'm looking for a fast to migrate Linux installation to another hardware.

As I wrote in another question ([Unable to access resume device in CentOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/110501/unable-to-access-resume-device-in-centos)), I moved 2 disks in software RAID to another hardware, and now it doesn't boot-up because the server has a SATA hardware controller not included in the initrd image.
I spent a whole day trying to solve this (with the very dear mkinitrd), but still to no avail.
It all probably gets complicated because I have a software raid running and the OS on top of it, and somewhere along the line it just doesn't work.

Anyway, I'm want now just to set-up a new mirrored raid, and move all the data from the old drives as fast as possible, with as least configuration as possible.

Is there a good way to do it? I heard DD should do the trick, but will it work later with the controller, or it just would overwrite all the disks and I will be back at the start?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: Forget about "fast". The right metric is "easy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best bet would be to rsync the data over. I would bring up the server, and set it to an initial "priming" rsync while the original server is still up and running. Then you can take a much smaller outage window to rsync the changed and locked files over to the new server when you are ready to put it into production.

Comment: When doing this, you have to avoid /proc /sys /dev, but you need the files 'under' /dev to bootstrap linux.

The trick i usually do is:

  mkdir /o
  mount -o bind / /o

and then you can rsync -avz /o/ destination:/